# Looking for an android solution for offline kml/kmz file viewer with gps support

Tags: kml, gps, android, kmz, offline

I have some KMZ files of cadastral maps. I need to fiscally go to the boundaries of my lands (parcels) and take a look at where they are with the gps and maps support. Some of these places are not covered by the phone network signal.

For this reason I'm looking for an android app that will import my kmz files and let me reach the boundaries position with gps help.

I've used google earth app, but gps position is not working.

Google maps engine app, instead, works well but only with online maps.

Any idea about an app to work offline?

Comment: I downloaded the Locus program. If this works, you're going to be my hero. I've been trying to walk my own property line with my phone for ages and Google Earth never shows the correct location with GPS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My favorite app for doing these kinds of things is [Locus map free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus). It can import KML file amongst many other formats, and can work completely offline.

If you need a base map, you can either download it within the app (for a fee) or add your own data either in mbtiles, or one of the other myriad formats that it supports.

Answer (score 1):

I have had great success with Galileo Offline Maps https://galileo-app.com/

Comment: Dink, this question is ages old and already answered. Why dig it up?

Comment: Came here 5 years after the original Q and answer, and 4 years after this additional answer. Both are still helpful and valuable; and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well Galileo is now guru and is not free anymore. I use maps.me but it works with gpx tracks, not kml(however converting kml into gpx and vise verse is easy and you can do it online)

Answer (score 0):

YourPlans is a simple but effective option:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AxelsApps.YourPlansLite
It can import and export KMLs of unlimited size. You can edit them as well with layers, markers and more.

Answer (score -1):

The Alpinequest app is the best, have a try.
Be succeed

Comment: Add some description, a supporting doc, or a link :)